# How to show the detail of a record of a DB with a modal in Classic ASP, Ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, asp-classic

I am trying to show the details of a record through a modal, what I am doing is with the help of a button, it detects an event, this event sends a  request to a file called query and in this file I make the query. It works well for me but what I want is to show the result in a modal that is in the file where I send the request.
This is my code:

Here I show the button where the event is:

```
<% Do While Not rs.EOF %>

         <div class="<% = RS("numPin") %>" data-xpos="<% = RS("coorX") %>" data-ypos="<% = RS("coorY") %>">  
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h2><% = RS("nombrecec") %></h2>  
              <button id="preguntaM1aColumnaA" name="preguntaM1aColumnaA" type="button" value="<% = RS("cec") %>"  class="btn btn-info " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="buscare(<%=RS(("cec"))%>);">VER INFORMACIÓN</button>
              </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
          <%
              rs.MoveNext
               Loop
               rs.Close
               Set rs = Nothing

            %>
```

This is my jquery:

```
<script >
      function buscare(cec){
       $(function() {
          $('#preguntaM1aColumnaA').load('consulta.asp?cec=' + cec, function(argument) {
            
             alert("Datos Cargados: " + argument);
            });
    });
    
      }
 </script>
```

This is my file called query:

```
<% @LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001" %>

<% 
  strConn = "DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=LAPTOP-DD7NHUOM; UID=sa; PWD=luis1931; DATABASE=PaginaWeb; Pooling=False;"
  Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  Conn.Open strConn
  query = "SELECT * FROM centros WHERE cec = ?"
  CustomerID = Request.QueryString("cec")
  arParams = array(CustomerID)
  Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  cmd.CommandText = query
  Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
  Set rs = cmd.Execute(,arParams,1)
  %> 
  <% If Not rs.EOF Then%> 
   
              <h2><% = RS("nombrecec") %></h2>  


   <% End If%> 
   <%  rs.Close : Set rs = Nothing : Set cmd = Nothing : Conn.Close : Set Conn = Nothing
  Response.End()
%>
```

This is my modal:

```
    div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;"> <h4 ></h4>
      <img src="img/piedrasnegras.jpg" width="180" height="180" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" ></div>
  </div>

</div>
      </div>
            </div>
```

Any suggestion would help me a lot. Thank you

Comment: Just make sure all the db conn string info is fake.

Comment: `$('#myModal').find('.row h4').text(argument);` instead of the alert.